# LINQ filtering on data only works during debug

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working with an N-Tier solution built around Entity Framework Code First and ASP.NET MVC 5.

I have the following ActionResult in my Artist Controller.

```
public ActionResult Paintings(string urlfriendly)
{
    var artist = _artistService.GetArtistByUrlFriendly(urlfriendly);
    ArtistPaintingsVM vm = Mapper.Map<ArtistPaintingsVM>(artist);

    return View(vm);
}
```

That service eventually arrives here:

```
public Artist GetArtistByUrlFriendly(string urlFriendly)
{
    var artist = _context.Artists.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UrlFriendly == urlFriendly && a.Verified);
    if (artist != null)
    {
        artist.Paintings = _context.Paintings.Where(p => p.ArtistId == artist.Id && p.Verified).ToList();
    }

    return artist;
}
```

When I step through that code, I get the desired result. I get the two verified paintings by that artist. However when I run the application without debugging I get all three paintings of the artist, even though one of them is not verified!

My code above, should only return paintings that are verified, and it does in debug, but not in normal running mode.

Here is the data seeding code:

```
    public class DXIntializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DXContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DXContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var artists = new List<Artist>
                {
                    new Artist { FName = "Salvador", LName = "Dali", ImgURL = "http://i62.tinypic.com/ss8txxn.jpg", UrlFriendly = "salvador-dali", Verified = true }
                };

                artists.ForEach(a => context.Artists.Add(a));
                context.SaveChanges();

                var paintings = new List<Painting>
                {
                    new Painting { Title = "The Persistence of Memory", ImgUrl = "http://i62.tinypic.com/xx8tssn.jpg", ArtistId = 1, Verified = true },
                    new Painting { Title = "Swans Reflecting Elephants", ImgUrl = "http://i62.tinypic.com/aa9tssn.jpg", ArtistId = 1, Verified = true },
                    new Painting { Title = "Crucifiction", ImgUrl = "http://i62.tinypic.com/qq0tssn.jpg", ArtistId = 1, Verified = false }
                };

                paintings.ForEach(p => context.paintings.Add(p));
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whrere does the value for `p.Verified` come from? Did you check (e.g. log) the value in Release mode?

Comment: `p.Verified` is set manually by me when I set my seed data on application start.

Comment: Please show more code...

Comment: @Sebastian I have gone ahead and added the seeding code, don't know what other parts of the code you think would be relevant, you can tell me and I'll add it :)

Comment: You haven't got a web.config transformation changing your connection string in the release build?

Comment: I've not set anything like that up and I'm guessing by default we get no such thing right? So I'd say no I haven't. :(

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code that is populating your Lists. It seems Artist.Id is not set. There should not be any results at all from that Linq query.

Comment: You don't need to set the ID of entities when adding them, EF automatically sets the ID property.

Comment: @Ciwan I am sure the code you posted in the question have no issue. Check your database table data, connection string in web.config. If possible log the count of that collection after filtering.

Comment: It is probably not enumerated when it's hitting the where clause. Have you tried calling 'ToList' first and then applying the 'Where' clause?

Comment: IMO the best way to debug this is to rewrite `GetArtistByUrlFriendly` to be a loop. Even if you want to use LINQ in the final code, for right now its not helping.

If the problem persists after changing the code to be a loop, i would wager that you will find out (using some logging) that p.Verified is indeed true for all 3 when that loop executes.

After that comes verifying your seeding function in release mode after you save the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Paintings` property of the `Artist` class is virtual, e.g.

```
public virtual List<Painting> Paintings { get; set; }
```

make it non-virtual ([turn off lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj574232#lazyOffProperty)), like so:

```
public List<Painting> Paintings { get; set; }
```

This fix should get your code going. If it is already non-virtual, please reveal the source code of these entities to help us understand the problem.

### Explanation + Few Recommendations

1. N-Tier solutions built using Entity Framework would most likely involve serialization of entities. In your case, the service (wcf or web api I suppose) used to retrieve data would serialize the Artist object and pass it on to the UI tier. Now, [lazy loading and serialization don't mix well.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj574232#lazySerialization) When serializer accesses the `Paintings` property, it ends up loading all paintings belonging to the artist because of lazy loading. While debugging, try this :  DO NOT check \ hover on artist object at all, also remove it from watch, set a breakpoint on `return artist;` statement. Hit F5, when execution pauses at the return statement, explore artist object, you should see all three paintings. Make sure there is NOTHING which triggers evaluation of the `Paintings` property before you assign value to it.
2. It is a good practice to declare navigation properties like so : `public List<Painting> Paintings { get; private set; }` This enforces the recommended way of using navigation properties. i.e. You can either add or remove item from collection, however, you cannot assign a new collection. It is important to initialize such properties in the default constructors as follows:

```
    public class Artist
    {    
        public List Paintings { get; private set; }    
        public Artist()
        {
            this.Paintings = new List();
        }
    }
```

3. When you turn off lazy loading, you must [explicitly load related entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj574232#explicitFilter).

In your case, instead of directly assigning values to the `Paintings` property, you should rather do the following:

```
            db.Entry<Artist>(artist)
            .Collection(a => a.Paintings)
            .Query()
            .Where(p => p.Verified)
            .Load();
```

It will only load verified paintings of the specified artist (lazy loading should be off).

Comment: Thanks @RaviMPatel. I did have the Paintings property as `virtual`!! Making it non-virtual fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

You should not set the property of the artist like that. Since this is a EF navigation property. When debugging it is loaded as soon your code hits the service (because your debugger reads the property) and is then overridden by the values of your linq statement. When running without debugging, it is more likely that the property is actually first read in the mapper (lazy loading) and the query executed is the one defined by EF.

If you need it only on one place, you shoud write it just once like

```
artist.Paintings.Where(p => p.Verified)
```

If you requiere it on multiple places you could make a property for it.
A proper way to do this is defining a extra property on your artist.

```
ICollection<Painting> VerifiedPaintings 
{
    get 
    {
         return this.Paintings.Where(p => p.Verified);
    }
}
```

When you want your service to retrun an object fully loaded (For example in case you dispose your DbContext when leaving the service). You should load it in a seperate list.

```
return new artistDto 
{
    Artist = artist ,
    VerifiedPaintings = artist.Paintings.Where(p => p.Verified)
}
```

Comment: I don't think the proper way would be to add a new property on my `Artist.cs` I've not seen that ... ever. :/

Comment: If you dont like that, you could also write artist.Paintings.Select(p=>p.Verified); where you need it. Or you could let return your service the verified paintings in a separate list. It is a concern of taste. The essence is that you should not set your property in that way.